# fbauth2 is missing after following all suggested solutions

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, exception, sdk

Good day everyone.

I have this error when I update my ios to ios 9.2

```
'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0'
```

After searching about this problem the solution was to add `fbauth2` key in the plist file `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` as the following.
 [image]

but even after doing that, the exception still the same, and "fbauth2" still missing ??

Do you have any solutions ?!

:(

Comment: can you show the source code of your plist

Comment: <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
 </array>

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9